# Vue2 component as <vue-component>value</vue-component>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

It is possible to pass a value to the component between the component tags?

Example: in a component to format value to money, I created as :

```
<vue-component value="50" />
```

and it display

```
$ 50,00
```

Now, just for curiosity, it is a way to call the component like these:

```
    <vue-component>50</vue-component>
```

Comment: You can do that using the slots functionality. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Usually you should use filters for these kinds of situations https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about slots: vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Fe: `<template><h1><slot/></h1></template>`

You can access ita value via: `this.$slots.default[0].text`

The fact that it's possible doesn't mean that you should do it. Actually, on the contrary. Props have multiple advantages (such as marking as required, default value, validators and many more) but in thr first place they are standardised way of passing data to children components every vuejs developer will understand.